# Show that the probability that $E$ appears on the nth time is $P(E)(1 − p)^ n−1$ where $p = P(E) + P(F).$

Tags: probability, proof-writing

Let $E$ and $F$ be mutually exclusive events in the sample space of an experiment.
Suppose that the experiment is repeated until either event $E$ or event
$F$ occurs. Let n be a positive integer. Show that the probability that $E$ appears on
the $n^{th}$ time is $P(E)(1 − p)^($$^n$$^−$$^1$$^)$ where $p = P(E) + P(F).$

So far, I have that $P$ = the probability of getting either $E$ or $F.$ 
Since $E$ and $F$ are mutually exclusive, $P(E)+P(F) = P$ and $P(EF)=0.$
The sample space = {$P^c$, $P^cP^c$, $P^cP^cP^c$...}

Then, I started by letting $X =$ "$E$ occurs on the $n^{th}$ time." $P(x) = P(E) + P^cP(E) + P^cP^cP(E)+\dots
=P(E) \times ( 1 +$ $P^c$ + $(P^c)^2$ $+ (P^{c})^{3}\dots)$ but then I get stuck from there.

Comment: Do you know about the [geometric distribution](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_distribution)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed, if $p=\mathsf P(E\cup F)$ then $(1-p) = \mathsf P(E^\complement\cap F^\complement)$.

$(1-p)^{n-1}\mathsf P(E)$ is therefore the probability for a particular sequence of $n-1$ trials where neither $E$ nor $F$ occur, and one trial where $E$ does occur.   One such sequence is of $n-1$ consecutive "failures" followed by one "success" of type-E.

Since the experiment terminates the first time that one of those events occurs, this is thus the probability that it does so on the $n^\textrm{th}$ trial *and* with event $E$.